# Elegant way to eliminate multiple condition checks in function

Tags: go

There are multiple condition checks in multiple functions

```golang
type VA struct {
    A string
}

func (va *VA) CheckA(s string) error {
    if s != va.A {
        return errors.New("invalid str ")
    }
    return nil
}

type VB struct {
    B int
}

func (vb *VB) CheckB(i int) error {
    if i == vb.B {
        return errors.New("invalid int")
    }
    return nil
}

func FuncA(s string, i int) error {
    a := &VA{A: "testa"}
    errA := a.CheckA(s)
    if errA != nil {
        return errA
    }

    b := &VB{B: 3}
    errB := b.CheckB(i)
    if errB != nil {
        return errB
    }

    // more logic ...

    return nil
}

func FuncB(sb string, v int32) error {
    a := &VA{A: "testb"}
    errA := a.CheckA(sb)
    if errA != nil {
        return errA
    }

    // more logic ...

    return nil
}

func FuncC(sc string, vv int) error {
    b := &VB{B: 3}
    errB := b.CheckB(vv)
    if errB != nil {
        return errB
    }

    // more logic ...

    return nil
}
```

We do `CheckA` and `CheckB` in function `FuncA` and do `CheckA` in function `FuncB`. However, only do `CheckB` in function `FuncC`. There is one pitfall that when the return value of `CheckA` is changed, both `FuncA` and `FuncB` would be changed.

We want to refactor the above codes. Is there any elegant way to do that in Golang?

What we have tried, combine `CheckA` and `CheckB` in one function `ValidateFunc` like below

```golang
type VALIDATE int

const (
    _ VALIDATE = 1 << iota
    VALIDATEA
    VALIDATEB
)

func ValidateFunc(vs, s string, vi, i int, validate VALIDATE) error {
    if validate&VALIDATEA == VALIDATEA {
        a := &VA{A: vs}
        errA := a.CheckA(s)
        if errA != nil {
            return errA
        }
    }
    if validate&VALIDATEB == VALIDATEB {
        b := &VB{B: vi}
        errB := b.CheckB(i)
        if errB != nil {
            return errB
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func FuncA(s string, i int) error {
    err := ValidateFunc("testa", s, 3, i, VALIDATEA|VALIDATEB)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // more logic ...

    return nil
}
```

Comment: I've applied the [option pattern](https://www.codedevlib.com/article/go-functional-options-pattern-22862) in the past for validation purpose too. See if this could be a good fit for you too. I can post a code sample if you are interested

Comment: Thank you Matteo, the option pattern come into my mind later

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Option pattern](https://golang.cafe/blog/golang-functional-options-pattern.html), it seems the codes will be simpler than before.

```golang
type Validator struct {
    A VA
    B VB
}

type Validate func(v *Validator) error

func WithVA(s string) Validate {
    return func(v *Validator) error {
        if err := v.A.CheckA(s); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    }
}

func WithVB(i int) Validate {
    return func(v *Validator) error {
        if err := v.B.CheckB(i); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    }
}

func DoValidate(vs string, vi int, vals ...func(v *Validator) error) error {
    v := &Validator{A: VA{A: vs}, B: VB{B: vi}}

    for _, val := range vals {
        if err := val(v); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func FuncA(s string, i int) error {
    err := DoValidate("testa", 3, WithVA(s), WithVB(i))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // more logic ...

    return nil
}
```

Comment: exactly, you can also write generic validator and apply where you need it

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps combine VA & VB into a new struct
Then validate that one?